# Which addTarget actions can we take on UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I want to use addTarget:action on UITextView like on (UITextField or UIButton).

I want to call a method on UITextView.

please give some possible solution...

Thank You...

```
UITextView  *TXT_First_Tag = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, textPosY, 350, 65)];
TXT_First_Tag.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
TXT_First_Tag.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:30.0];
TXT_First_Tag.editable =YES;
TXT_First_Tag.tag = i; 
TXT_First_Tag.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];


[TXT_First_Tag addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd]; //  This Line I want to use, it's working fine on textfield...
[scrollview addSubview:TXT_First_Tag];
```

Comment: I know this question is old, but I thought I'd point out the fact that the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method is inherited in `UITextField` and `UIButton` from `UIControl`.  The `UITextView` doesn't inherit from `UIControl`.  So the answer to the question in the title is none.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use UITextView delegate methods for this purpose.

Put this in your code.

```
UITextView  *TXT_First_Tag = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, textPosY, 350, 65)];
TXT_First_Tag.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
TXT_First_Tag.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:30.0];
TXT_First_Tag.editable =YES;
TXT_First_Tag.delegate  =   self;
TXT_First_Tag.tag = i; 
TXT_First_Tag.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[scrollview addSubview:TXT_First_Tag];

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"Begin editing");
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"DidEndEditing");
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"ShouldBeginEditing");
    return TRUE;
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"ShouldEndEditing");
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your controller implements the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol, you can then set the controller as the **text view's** delegate in the controller's instance method, `viewDidLoad()`:

```
yourTextView.delegate = self;
```

Then, if you want to perform a task before editing your **text view**, use:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {}
```

And, if you want to do a task after editing your **text view**, use:

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely a better way of getting the "editing did end" message is by implementing the `UITextViewDelegate`?

```
TXT_First_Tag.delegate = self;

... 

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  // stuff you'd put in C6Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaps,
Even though your responses did not directly solve my problem, it helped me narrow it down.

I have textviews in each cell and needed to pass which text view was being edited so I could update the database.

In a nutshell I set each textview tag in each cell to the indexpath.row.  I  then reference that cell in the delegate by textview.tag

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {  


    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"frontCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = mainPageCell;
    self.mainPageCell = nil;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }    


    UITextView *trackDetails;
    trackDetails = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
    trackDetails.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    trackDetails.delegate = self;
    trackDetails.tag = indexPath.row;


    }

    - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
    NSLog(@"%d",textView.tag);
    UPDATE DATABASE WITH CHANGED TEXT
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```